# Vue - JS Plugins attaching to wrong form inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pickadate

I've got a multi stage form using Vue.js to hide each section with `v-if` on the `div`.

Stage one has 2 fields:

1. an address search (crafty clicks)
2. date field using [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) plugin

Both of these work fine but when clicking **next** and going to the final step, the *pickadate* plugin is wrongly attaching to the `last name` text field

I make no reference to the *pickadate* on this field

If I inspect the text field in chrome dev tools, I can see the various pickadate classes/attributes have been attached to `last name` input

If I delete `last name` and run through the form, the same happens to the `email` field, so it seems to be whichever text input is the 2nd one. Presumably because the date field is the 2nd text field in the previous view

**1st Form Partial**

```
<div v-if="addressView" class="form-partial">

   <div class="form-group">            
        <input type="text" id="search-bar" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pickadate" placeholder="Date of Birth" v-model="dob">
    </div>

    <div class="next-row">
        <a @click="selectAddress()" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**2nd Partial**

```
<div v-if="contactView" class="form-partial">

    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="title" v-model="title">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>Mr</option>
            <option>Mrs</option>
            <option>Ms</option>
            <option>Miss</option>
            <option>Dr</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="firstName" placeholder="First Name(s)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" v-model="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>

    <div class="next-row">
        <input type="submit" @click.prevent="submitForm()" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS Code**

```
answerQuestions: function() {

this.questionView = false;
this.addressView  = true;

this.$nextTick(function() {

    $('#pickadate').pickadate({
        selectYears: 70,
        selectMonths: true,
        min: new Date(1930,1,1),
        max: new Date(1998,1,1) , 
        showMonthsShort: true, 
        onSet: function(context) {

            vm.dob = vm.formatDOB(context.select);
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: jQuery (`$('#pickadate')`) works outside of the VueJS life cycle and messes with data structure. Check this forum post:  https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-model-with-pickadate-js-input/20787/2.   BTW: You should avoid manipulating the DOM in VueJS in general, use the data layer instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I dont think that post is the same issue. I'm already using pickadate's callback function to update to vue data property, and that is working fine. The issue is that after doing that, pickadate is then attaching to the wrong input. I've only just started using vue so am not familiar with the data layer but will look into it.

Comment: Sure, that's why it's a comment and not an answer :) Further reading for Vue's data-driven concept: https://medium.com/@darrenjennings/data-driven-vue-js-53e84f16e28f

Comment: I don't see when `answerQuestions` is being called, but I'd suggest using `v-show` instead of `v-if` for your partials (less chance to run into trying to attach pickadate to a non-rendered input).